# fseek() API in C and error code

Tags: c, fseek

I am trying to run below code and expecting error as *[EBADF]  The stream is NULL*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()    
{    
   FILE *fp;
   char ch;

   fp=fopen("test33.txt","r");

   fseek(fp,0L,SEEK_SET);

   while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
     putchar(ch);
}
```

Output:

```
/home/akhils/file_dir#./a.out
Memory fault(coredump)
```

Through which utility can I see error [EBADF]? I am running this C Program on HP-UX box and using a C++ compiler by HP.

I rewrote the  code as below as per suggestion:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
extern int errno;
int main ()
{ 
  FILE *fp;
  int val;

  char ch;

  fp=fopen("test33.txt","r");
  if(fp==NULL)
    printf("\n Error code for fopen is : %d\n",errno);
  else
  {
    val=fseek(fp,0L,SEEK_SET);
    if(val!=0)
      val=errno;
    else {
      while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
      putchar(ch);
    }
    printf("\nError code for fseek is %d\n",val);
  }
}
Output : /home/akhils/file_dir#./a.out

 Error code for fopen is : 2
```

My question is and sorry if I am asking it in wrong sense that how would I know that error is  "[EBADF]           The fildes argument is not a valid file descriptor." Note : EABDF is ALSO error set for `fopen()` when a NULL pointer is returned by fopen i.e in case of unsuccessfull completion of `fopen()`.

Comment: 1. check the return codes and handle the errors properly.. 2. use gdb

Comment: its possible you may be interested in [perror](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/perror/) : having detected an error condition setting errno, this will interpret errno and print the system error message

Comment: @amdixon have made use of perror  and below is what ( close enough to what I want but I was expecting specifically EBADF "The fildes argument is not a valid file descriptor." in case of fopen error) :                                  Output :Error code for fopen is : 2
Error printed by perror : No such file or directory

Comment: so the EBADF return code referenced below is an error condition on the fseek. since we are now properly handling errors, the program has stopped now when it hits the fact that that file doesnt exist ( or possibly cant be accessed ). if you adjust the path ( /access ) to fix, everything will work

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, you should be checking for the success of `fopen()`, as if it fails, passing the returned pointer (`NULL`) will invoke  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in `fseek()`. You should not be using the returned pointer any further if `fopen()` failed.

That said, to detect the error in `fseek()` itself, you should be checking the return value of `fseek()` for success (or error). In case, `fseek()` is failure, it will set the `errno` variable. You can check the same against the `EBADF`.

You don't need any *utility* as such to check the error code. You can use `#include <errno.h>` with you code and you can access the `errno` variable value.

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek) for `fseek()`,

> [...] `fgetpos()`, `fseek()`, `fsetpos()` return 0, and `ftell()` returns the current offset. **Otherwise, -1 is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.**

and regarding the `EBADF`, as you mentioned,

> `EBADF`
>   The stream specified is not a seekable stream.

Comment: user should check that fp is not null and go no further ( as proper practice ). if you call fseek on null pointer, then user will hit a segfault..

Comment: If the `fopen()` returns NULL, `fseek()` has undefined behaviour.  Segfault is only one of many possible symptoms of that.   Also, to use `fseek()` it is generally advisable to open the file in binary mode.

Comment: I rewrote something like below . My question is and sorry if I am asking it in wrong sense , that how would I know that this error is " [EBADF]           The fildes argument is not a valid file descriptor.": Note: EBADF also correspond to fopen error and gets set when null pointer is returned by fopen() .

Comment: @theartist33 You need to check for error in (after) _each_ function call and handle the error cases. Thus, in this case, you can have two seperate checks for `fopen()` and `ftell()` to detect any error in any of them.

Comment: @theartist33 Yes, it can be seen from the output that `fopen()` is failing, so you should not call `fseek()` with that pointer at all. YOu're correct to put the `fseek()` in `else` block. What's your question?

Comment: @SouravGhosh    My question from the starting was that how do I know that error code is EABDF , how can I see it in output , is there any utility like valgrind or something which is genrally use to check mem leaks.

Comment: as per the linked manpage for fseek in the answer: Otherwise, -1 is returned and `errno` is set to indicate the error.  regarding the error condition for fopen: Otherwise, a null pointer is returned.
On most library implementations, the errno variable is also set to a system-specific error code on failure

Answer (score 0):

You should at least check if the file can actually be opened:

```
   ...
   fp=fopen("test33.txt","r");
   if (fp == NULL)  
   {
     // abort if file cannot be opened
     printf("Cannot open file");
     return 1;
   }

   ...
```